# Replace value of string in php?

Tags: php, string, preg-replace, str-replace

I have this string:

```
$string=<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" 
marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="www.yourwebiste.com"></iframe>
```

I want replace width from 425 to 248 and height 350 to 160?

I have tried with

```
str_replace('"350"', '"160"', $string);
```

But i got no luck

Comment: Could you post the actual code you have that won't work? As it is the $string is not even properly encapsulated in quotes so it can't be valid PHP code; if str_replace isn't working, there might be a problem somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

As meustrus mentioned, first of all you need to put quotes around $string.

To replace the values you can use a single str_replace:

```
$string='<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="www.yourwebiste.com"></iframe>';
$newString = str_replace(array('425', '350'), array('248', '160'), $string);
```

Comment: Beat me to it. This will work. If it get's more complicated or you don't know the numbers but want to set height and width you could try preg_replace with a basic regex

Comment: Nice but i can not to this only numbers, because in www.mywebsite.com, maybe sometimes i have ?id=425?

Comment: `str_replace('www.yourwebiste.com', 'http://www.yourwebiste.com')` will also work.

Comment: You don't have numbers it's all a string. 425 is  a string in this context so it's treated the same as the URL so you can use the same function

Comment: Ok sometimes i have $string='<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="www.yourwebiste.com?425"></iframe>';
$newString = str_replace(array('425', '350'), array('248', '160'), $string); What to do now, i dont want to replace ?425 i want only from width?

Comment: Then do str_replace('350', '160', $string) basic php stuff. Check out php.net

Comment: Not basic, this way i change all 350 to 160, i dont want that:(

Comment: you can do `str_replace('width="425"', 'width="350"', $string);`